# 2 date columns between another 2 date columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have 4 date columns- From_Date_A, To_Date_A, From_Date_B, To_Date_B. I want to create a flag column to flag anything where any date between From_Date_A and To_Date_A is between From_Date_B and To_Date_B. Is this possible?

Comment: do you have an example for your question? cannot understand the question very well

Answer (score 1):

Using a `case` expression to check for overlapping date ranges:

```
select *
  , case when To_Date_A > From_Date_B 
          and To_Date_B > From_Date_A 
        then 1 
        else 0 
        end as Flag
from t
```

This is assuming that an overlap does not include the initial dates for the range.

If it should, then:

```
select *
  , case when To_Date_A >= From_Date_B 
          and To_Date_B >= From_Date_A 
        then 1 
        else 0 
        end as Flag
from t
```

[In depth explanation of this overlap check by Charles Bretana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/2333499)

Comment: That is perfect! I appreciate it a lot! Also, since I'm new, how can I show an example with the data I want in columns and rows?

Comment: @ajc101 You can use this to create text tables https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/ from tab-delimited data (copied from excel or something), and format them as code on stackoverflow

Comment: @ajc101 Accept an answer if you find it useful.